# Entity Framework (Add/Create) Object reference not set to an instance of an object... but it is?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity

I'm using entity framework to access an exsisting database. I can access the data but when I try to add new data I get a NullReferenceException "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", but it is?

The DB connection is fine, I can access the data just fine:  `List<log> logs = db.log.ToList();`

The exception is thrown when using Add or Create:

```
db.log.Add(new log());
db.log.Create();
```

StackTrace:

```
at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Create()
```

UPDATE:

The Error only occurs OUTSIDE the namespace containing the DB Context. I can work around it by wrapping the classes to have their 'Add to DB context'-methods in the DBHandler namespace. But I would like an explanation to why this happens. Is it a bug or am I violating some sacred .net law?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Is there any "requied" field in you log table?

Comment: Yes there is, but if anything was missing I would get a "Cannot insert the value NULL into column ...." exception. The problem is related to the namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
using (db = new xxxxxEntities())
        {
           List<log> logs = db.log.ToList();
           db.log.Add(new log());
           db.log.Create();
        }
```